# Disable button depending on the result of Observable<Boolean>

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a button which I only want to show if the user has edit rights. To check this I need to call another service and the result is stored in `Observable<Boolean>`.

I was trying to do it like this but it doesn't work:

```
 <button md-mini-fab [disabled]="(blockButtonAsync() | async)" ...
```

Method is:

```
blockButtonAsync(): Observable<Boolean> {
    return this.http.get(this.restGetUserRoles)
                    .map(res => {
                                    return res.json() || [];
                                })
                    .map(roles => roles.indexOf('ROLE_EDITOR') === -1);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create observable variable and use it in template

```
// Ts code

$blockButton:Observable<boolean>;
ngOnInit() {
   this.$blockButton = this.http.get(this.restGetUserRoles)
     .pipe(
        map(roles => roles.indexOf('ROLE_EDITOR') === -1)
     );
}


//Html code

<button md-mini-fab [disabled]="$blockButton  | async)">
```

Try this. It may work

Comment: please, not use the old and deprecated http else httpClient

Comment: Isn't standard notation for observables trailing $?